# Custom application class randomly NOT overridden in Nougat

Tags: java, android

I have a custom application, called the ProApplication, which I define in the manifest like this:

```
    <application
       android:name=".ProApplication"
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:fullBackupContent="false"
       android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
```

It is working fine and dandy, and I do all basic app initialisations in the onCreate() method of that class. 
But randomly I get crashes because when I call getApplication() and cast it to ProApplication, I get a classCastException. It thinks that getApplication() should return Application, and not my overriden ProApplication.

This only happens on android version 7.0, and on very few app launches. But the most common devices when these crashes occur are these:

1. Honor 9 (HWSTF) 8   25,8 %
2. Honor 8 Pro (HWDUK) 8   25,8 %
3. P10 Plus (HWVKY)    7   22,6 %
4. Honor 8 (HWFRD) 5   16,1 %
5. P10 (HWVTR) 3   9,7 %

So my question is, why is my overriden application class, ProApplication, randomly ignored by the OS on devices running android 7.0?

Comment: the java stacktrace shows why the cast exception is thrown, so what do you see?

Comment: I did not include it, since I am unable to recreate this bug myself. In the reports of the class cast exception in the dev console, it only points to the line where it is happening, and the only class casting I do on that line is casting Application to ProApplication.

Comment: I shall mention also that this issue eluded me for a long while, since I initialise Crashlytics in ProApplication onCreate method, and when the random crashes happened, Crashlytics was never initialised...

Comment: ok do you have to use custom `Application` class at all? the docs say: `"Note: There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situations, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way"`

Comment: I am not using it to hold any data or such. I am only using it to initialise things used in the app, like Crashlytics, Dagger, MultiDex and the DB. According to the documentation for all those libs, it should go into the Application class onCreate method. When my overriden application class is randomly ignored, nothing will work in the app. It will basically crash everywhere.

Comment: it seems that there are two cases here: 1) your custom `ProApplication` is ignored and thus its `onCreate` not called and 2) it is not ignored but simply `Activity#getApplication()` returns base `android.app.Application` class instance - are you sure your case is #1?

Comment: Yes I am sure it is case #1. I added the casting in the latest app update to verify my theory. Before I didn't do the class casting, then I got null pointer exceptions because Dagger was not initialised. I searched for a long time to understand why Dagger failed, and then I realised that the crashes was not reported either by Crashlytics, so then I figured that my ProApplication never ran, and verified it by running the casting from Application to ProApplication.  Everything is working for 99.8% of my users. I want tu understand why it fails randomly for the last 0.2%...

Comment: I currently have a P10 Lite with Nougat on it and also have a custom `Application` class that calls stuff in `onCreate`. However I don't use `getApplication` in my code and didn't face any issues so far.

Comment: Yes I have also tried with the top devices from which I get the most frequent crashes. Never been able to reproduce this myself. There must be some kind of corner case where the app is launched and the OS decides to use the default application class.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a Android 7.0 OS bug. 
I finally found this link:
[issutracker.google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137009)

With the following answer:

> Status: Won't Fix (Obsolete)
>   Yes, this is a known issue; and was largely addressed in 7.1.  There are still some edge cases in 7.1 that can result in similar circumstances -- as you can see from your analytics -- but the window of opportunity is much narrower, and Android 8 addressed those as well.

So basically the only way to solve the issue is to remove the custom application class. And if you must have one, then the only fix known to man is to recommend your users to restart the phone if they run in to this issue. Clearing app data och remove the app from memory does not work.