# Android extended application is not created

Tags: android, android-context

1. MyApplication extends Application.
2. MyApplication.java

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application {
   @Override
       protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
           super.attachBaseContext(base);
           MultiDex.install(this);
       }
   }
   ```
3. AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <application android:name="com.my.app.MyApplication">
   ```
4. tergetSdkVersion is 23
5. compileSdkVersion is 26
6. use multidex 
   (multidex library is 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')

The problem is sometimes MyApplication is not created. (not always)
It seems like default Application instance is created NOT MyApplication.

!!! This problem occurs after targetSdkVersion update 18 ->23.

Comment: Have you registered it in `Android.Manifest` under <application>?

Comment: Yes, I did register it in AndroidManifest.xml under <application>.

Comment: make tergetSdkVersion 26 too

Comment: @Cottonfloss how you identified application class not created some time?what you have performed in application class?

Comment: I found same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377476/custom-application-class-randomly-not-overridden-in-nougat.

Comment: @AxborAxrorov
Do you min targetSdkVersion update to 26? Why do you guess targetSdkVersion effects this problem?? Actually, the problem occurs after targetSdkVersion update 18 ->23.

Comment: @cottonfloss yes, try to update targetSdkVersion to equal compileSdkVerion

Answer (score 0):

This is how your application class looks like if you are using `MultiDex`

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication{

@Override
 public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
}
}
```

If you go through to the `MultiDexApplication`, this is the code in a .class file.

```
public class MultiDexApplication extends Application {
    public MultiDexApplication() {
    }

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

So if you want to override `attachBaseContext` for your custom implementation you can override that method otherwise there is no need to override. Because above I am extending `MyApplication` class with `MultiDexApplication` class.

and you have to register your Application class in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

That you have already done.

And your build.gradle (Application level) looks like

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

and for further reference, you can go through to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)